# How do I keep count of how many times something has been printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to print out a while loop for two dice rolling, and they will continue to roll until both dice are 1 and 1, in which case they are both Odd numbers, are Doubles. However, if they roll any other number, say 2 and 2 for example, it would be considered Evens, and Doubles. At the end, I want to keep a count of how many times the dice has rolled until both roll 1s, and how often Odds, Evens, and Doubles has occurred. I'll just include a section of the code, since the whole program is too lengthy.

I'm not sure where to begin, and I'm new to python.

```
condition2 = False

while condition2 == False:
    count = 0

    die1 = random.randint(1,sides+1)
    die2 = random.randint(1,sides+1)

   
    evens = "Evens!"
    odds = "Odds!"
    doubles = "Doubles!"
    snake_eye = "Snake Eyes!"
    sum_value = "Sum is size value!"
    highroll = "High Roll!"
    high_low_roll = "High/Low Roll!"
    low_high_roll = "Low/High Roll!"

    if die1 % 2 == 0 and die2 % 2 == 0: #For the even numbers
        if die1 == die2 and die1 + die2 == sides: #For even numbers that add up to sum value
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles, sum_value)
        elif die1 == 6 and die2 == 6: #For high roll
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles, highroll)
        elif die1 + die1 == die2: #Even numbers that are equal
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles)
        else: #Even numbers that are simply even, nothing else
            print("die #1 is", "*" + str(die1) + "*", "and die #2 is", "*" + str(die2) + "*", evens)
```

Comment: When is `condition2` gonna be true? And what's `sides`

Comment: you can probably create a variable outside the loop with value 0 and inside the loop increase its value whenever something's gotta get printed and print the value of variable at the end

Comment: condition2 is gonna be true when both dice roll 1s. sides was an input for the user that asks how many sides their dice are.

Comment: thank you so much, originally my count was not correct because i made the variable INSIDE the loop, so every time I printed the variables out, they would say 1. Now I tried putting it outside of the loop, and it prints the correct variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just define `counters` for each situation; for example, you need `counters` for counting `even` , `odd` , `doubles` , `snake_eye`, `sum_value` , `highroll` , and etc , events.
It seems you didn't implement the `Odd` part of the program, It is so simple, you just need to add an `else` for odd numbers and with a little change in the `even` part, you can make it suitable for `odd`s.

```py
import random

sides = 6
while True: 

    die1 = random.randint(1,sides+1)
    die2 = random.randint(1,sides+1)

    # Initialize the counters for each situation
    even_counter = 0
    odds_counter = 0 
    doubles_counter = 0
    sanke_eye_counter = 0
    sum_value_counter = 0
    highroll_counter = 0
    highlow_counter = 0
    lowhigh_counter = 0

    evens = "Evens!"
    odds = "Odds!"
    doubles = "Doubles!"
    snake_eye = "Snake Eyes!"
    sum_value = "Sum is size value!"
    highroll = "High Roll!"
    high_low_roll = "High/Low Roll!"
    low_high_roll = "Low/High Roll!"

    if die1 % 2 == 0 and die2 % 2 == 0: #For the even numbers
        if die1 == die2 and die1 + die2 == sides: #For even numbers that add up to sum value
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles, sum_value)
            even_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1; sum_value += 1
        elif die1 == 6 and die2 == 6: #For high roll
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles, highroll)
            even_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1; highroll_counter += 1
        elif die1 + die1 == die2: #Even numbers that are equal
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", evens, doubles)
            even_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1
        else: #Even numbers that are simply even, nothing else
            print("die #1 is", "*" + str(die1) + "*", "and die #2 is", "*" + str(die2) + "*", evens)
            even_counter += 1
    else:
        if die1 == 1 and die2 == 1: # End of the rolls
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", odds, doubles, sum_value)
            odds_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1; sum_value += 1
            break # end of the while loop
        elif die1 == die2 and die1 + die2 == sides: #For odd numbers that add up to sum value
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", odds, doubles, sum_value)
            odds_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1; sum_value += 1
        elif die1 + die1 == die2: #Odd numbers that are equal
            print("die #1 is", "*"+str(die1)+"*", "and die #2 is", "*"+str(die2)+"*", odds, doubles)
            odds_counter += 1; doubles_counter += 1
        else: #Odd numbers that are simply even, nothing else
            print("die #1 is", "*" + str(die1) + "*", "and die #2 is", "*" + str(die2) + "*", odds)
            odds_counter += 1
```

Comment: when I try to print out the counter, for example print(odds_counter), it just prints 1, even though there were much more odds. I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you could give me more detail or data, I could help you @altalio